# SAS frequency of category divisions

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data have;
input county $ city $ state $ quantity;
cards;
A Springfield AZ 1000
A Townsville AZ 1000
A Selma AZ 1000
A Dunno AZ 1000
B City NC 2000
B Town NC 1000
B Village NC 2000
C Springfield AZ 2000
C Fargo AZ 1000
;
run;
```

I am trying to count how many distinct counties and cities there are within each state and also sum up quantity per state.  So, the end goal would be:

```
data want;
    input state $ freq_counties freq_cities sum_quantity;
cards;
AZ 2 6 7000
NC 1 3 5000
;
run;
```

Here is what I have and this ALMOST works.  There are two occurrences of Springfield, AZ and this SQL counts it only once (which, of course, is exactly what it is supposed to do).  However, since they are different counties I want them to be counted separately.  I thought about concatenating county and city to make a third variable, but would rather not if there is an easier way. Ideas?

```
proc sql;
create table test as
    select state
    ,count(distinct(county))
    ,count(distinct(city))
    ,sum(quantity)
    from have
    group by 1;
quit;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
    select state
    ,count(distinct(cats(county,city)))
    ,count(distinct(city))
    ,sum(quantity)
    from have
    group by 1;
```

Concatenation **is** your best choice here..

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  Guess I was on the right track, but didn't need to create a variable, just a concatenation to count.